# Get the select2 search box values and append it in drop down

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to get the search-box text and append it in the dropdown list of select box. I have wasted hours on this but did not get any help.
Check here [Documentation](https://select2.org/)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

    <select style="width: 200px;" id="single">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
<script>
$('select').select2({
      language: {
         noResults: function(term) {
            var value = $('.select2-search__field').val();
           return "Click on above Add button."+value;
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear to understand. What's your expected output?

Comment: You want whatever they type to be added to the list if it is not already there?
RTM! https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Comment: One problem you'll run into if you allow dynamic updates to the select list is that the option value can only be the option's text: no user will know that there is in fact an invisible option value for any given option item.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal  I just want to give the option to add the state if its not already there so i need to add it in list and updated in database later.

Comment: @mplungjan I know it not allow to me do so but it is my requirement.

Comment: What is not allowed? Looks like you can add whatever you want

Comment: @SaschaM78 The documentation does not disallow adding new options...

Comment: @mplungjan where in my comment does it say "you are not allowed to add new options"? All I said is: if you give the user the possibility to add new items dynamically, the option value of the added element will necessarily be the typed text given by the user as the user won't give an option value and text separately. To be more verbose: if the user adds "Florida", you will get an `<option value="Florida">Florida</option>` and not one like `<option value="FL">Florida</option>`

Comment: @SaschaM78 ah - that is correct. We could ask...

Answer (score 3):

Using the documentation I came up with this

It might be more correct or simpler to use the select2 `.data` but this does work

```js
var typed = "";
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  language: {
    noResults: function(term) {
      typed = $('.select2-search__field').val();
    }
  }
  
});
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  typed = ""; // clear
});
$("#but").on("click", function() {
  if (typed) {
      // var value = prompt("Do you have a state abbriviation for "+typed+"?"); // change typed to value where necessary

    // Set the value, creating a new option if necessary
    if ($('#mySelect2').find("option[value='" + typed + "']").length) {
      $('#mySelect2').val(typed).trigger('change');
    } else {
      // Create a DOM Option and pre-select by default
      
      var newOption = new Option(typed, typed, true, true); 
      // Append it to the select
      $('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select style="width: 200px;" id="mySelect2">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    </select>
<button type="button" id="but" data-target="#single">Add </button>
```

Perhaps you wanted this?

You can add

```
var value = prompt("Do you have a state abbriviation for "+typed+"?");
```

if you need the two letter abbreviation in the value

```js
var typed = "";
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  language: {
    noResults: function(term) {
      typed = $('.select2-search__field').val();
      if (typed.length>3) getState()
    }
  }

});
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  typed = ""; // clear
});
function getState() {
  if (typed) {
    id = prompt("Do you have a state abbriviation for " + typed + "?", ""); // change typed to value where necessary
    if (id = "") return;

    // Set the value, creating a new option if necessary
    if ($('#mySelect2').find("option[value='" + id + "']").length) {
      $('#mySelect2').val(typed).trigger('change');
    } else {
      // Create a DOM Option and pre-select by default

      var newOption = new Option(typed, id, true, true);
      console.log(newOption)
      // Append it to the select
      $('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select style="width: 200px;" id="mySelect2">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Can i add it without on click on add button. Actually  i want to append on tab press of select2 search-box it its not in list add it in option with empty values. I have 3-4 select box on same page.

Comment: See update - I have on noresult, you could use on blur too

Comment: Its appending only at first attempt and what will be if i want to use the multiple select lets suppose i have 4 select box i.e 1) Continent, 2) Country, 3) State, 4) City

Comment: Please try some stuff yourself. SO is not an elance site

Comment: Thank you for you support :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

```
 // Create a DOM Option and pre-select by default
    var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);
    // Append it to the select
    $('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

In your case would be something like:

```
<select style="width: 200px;" id="single">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="code" placeholder="State Code" />
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="State Name" />

<button type="button" id="add">Add </button>

<script>
   $("#add").click(function(){
      var code = $("#code").val();
      var state = $("#name").val();

      //TODO PUT SOME VALIDATION

    var newOption = new Option(code, state, true, true);
    // Append it to the select
    $('select').append(newOption).trigger('change');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: That's great its working fine but i don't want to show the add button there i want to add it just after search if it show not found

Answer (score 0):

**Finally here is the Answer this is what i was looking for hope it will help someone and save there time.**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select style="width: 200px;" id="continent">
      <option value="AL">Asia</option>
      <option value="AK">Europe</option>
</select>
<script>
    //var value = prompt("Do you have a state abbriviation for "+typed+"?");

  var typed = "";
    $('#continent').select2({
      language: {
        noResults: function(term) {
            console.log(event.target.value);
            typed = event.target.value;
            if (typed.length>4){
                continentVal = prompt("Sorry ! Not found any continent do you want to add new continent"); 
                console.log(' === '+continentVal);              
                if (continentVal != ""){
                    console.log('Here we go '+event.target.value+ continentVal);
                    // Create a DOM Option and pre-select by default
                    var newOption = new Option(continentVal,continentVal, true, true);
                    // Append it to the select
                    $('#continent').append(newOption).trigger('change');
                }
            }
        }
      }
    });

</script>
```